# Tutorial for NodeJS's htmlparser?

Tags: node.js, html-parsing

I don't really understand the [readme of htmlparser](https://github.com/tautologistics/node-htmlparser/).. and I searched over the internet but cannot find a proper tutorial for it (or other NodeJS parsers).

I believe for most of the time if there's no tutorial for a pretty complete and old library it's mostly because that it's easy to do thus people don't really feel the need to write tutorial for it... But I found NodeJS html parser is pretty hard to understand...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should check out [htmlparser2](https://npmjs.org/package/htmlparser2).  It's the newer htmlparser and it's got a decent readme.  The way I tend to use it isn't streamish, and thus looks something like this:

```
handler = new htmlparser.DomHandler(function(err, dom) {
    // ... DO CODE HERE
})
new htmlparser.Parser(handler).parseComplete(html_string)
```

For the code inside the handler function, I use [soupselect](https://github.com/harryf/node-soupselect) because it's documented and I'm lazy, but htmlparser2 guys suggest domutils, but it has no documentation.

Comment: Do you know how to manipulate the DOM using `htmlparser2` ? Their readme doesn't show any examples. It says it's possible using the `DomParser` and `DomUtils` which come built-in but I have no idea how.